# How to manipulate unity objects in a C# script?

Tags: unity

I am new to unity and i was wanting to know how i can change a objects position and angles and stuff like that in a c# script. I exported the object from blender as .3ds. The objects name is sphere.3ds. please show and explain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and easy way to do this would be just to pass in the object as a variable.

Creating a public GameObject variable in a script will allow an object to be handed to it from the Unity interface.

```
public GameObject testObject;
```

Then when you go back into unity you can see a new box appeared in the script module. You can then drag the object you want to manipulate into that box that says `"None (Game Object)"` and it'll be passed into your script as that variable.

[image]

To then manipulate that object's position, you can just use its transform and do as you please. It's the object's transform variable which determines its position, rotation, etc.

```
Vector3 objectPos = testObject.transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = testObject.transform.rotation;
```

Also, the transform variable already supplies you with useful functions that you can mess around with, like Translate and RotateAround.

To rotate an object around an axis, use

```
testObject.transform.RotateAround(testObject.transform.position, Vector3.up, 90)
```

The first parameter is the position of the rotation, the second is the axis you want to rotate around, say up, left, right, etc.. And the third is the amount you want to rotate it by.

Comment: I added the public gameobject code but i don't see that box.

Comment: Have you added the script to any object? And in addition, you can't name your GameObject variable `object`

Comment: One more thing using the Quaternion code how would i rotate the object 90 degrees?

Comment: To do that, I would use `testObject.transform.RotateAround(testObject.transform.position, Vector3.up, angle)` The angle parameter is just how much you want it to rotate, so in your case: 90. And the Vector3.up is the axis you want to rotate it around. In this example. Vector3.up will rotate it around its y axis. Vector3.right will  rotate it around its right-pointing axis, etc.

Comment: Unity says it has no errors but the object dosnt seem to be moving. my code sphere.transform.RotateAround(sphere.transform.position, Vector2.up, 90);

Comment: Check to see if your sphere variable is null or not.

Comment: Which method are you calling it aswell? Remember it needs to be in the Update() method if you want it to be called every tick.